# SVG height scaling not as expected

Tags: javascript, css, svg, flexbox

I have a two column layout and I want to draw an svg on left and some elements on the right. I want the SVG's height to scale as per the height of 2nd column(i.e one on the right). To achieve two column layout, I have used flex-box css. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saiki4116/25y3ateo/1/) showing the problem.

Could anyone help me out what I am doing wrong.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <svg style="width:100%;height:100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="#E61875" rx='10' ry='10' />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.</div>
</div>
```

The desired result is if the height of the 2nd Div increases, SVG's height should also increased, similarly if the height of the 2nd Div decreases, then SVG's height should decrease.

I have updated the fiddle, it seems to be working in firefox, but in chrome, it is setting up height as 150px and not changing the value. I still didn't find the work around.

Comment: You might want to set  height attribute  on SVG and RECT through JS

Comment: @maioman, I need to find the computed height of 2nd div and update the the height of 1st div and SVG. I am actually trying to develop a custom directive in Angular, but didn't find a reliable way to find the computed height(offsetHeight), so I was trying for css based solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the issue is as your JSfiddle does not contain the SVG.

For the SVG to be the full height of the column you would need to remove the padding *and* set the SVG to `display:block`.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div style="width:60px;height:100%;">
      <svg style="width:100%;height:100%" viewbox="0 0 50 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="#E61875" rx='10' ry='10' />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, it's not clear what this final result is *supposed* to look like. I suspect some adjustments may be required.

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle, what's happening is that, once SVG is rendered, as per the initial height of container,but when the container heights are changed, SVG's height is not changing.